# How to understand asymptotic normality under constraints?

Tags: statistical-inference, maximum-likelihood, constraints

Consider the following constrained maximum likelihood problem:
\begin{align*}
\min\limits_{\theta \in \mathbb R^d}~ & -\log p(x_{1:n};\theta) \\
{\rm s.t.} ~~& f(\theta)=0.
\end{align*}

Let $F(\theta)=\nabla^\top f(\theta)$, and $U(\theta)$ be a matrix satisfies $F(\theta)U(\theta)=0$ and $U^\top(\theta)U(\theta)=I$. In addition, define $B(\theta)=U(\theta)(U^\top(\theta)FU(\theta))^{-1}U^\top(\theta)$, where $F$ is the Fisher information matrix. Then, paper [1] states that under some regularity conditions, the constrained maximum likelihood estimate $\hat \theta_n$ is asymptotically normal, i.e.,
\begin{equation*}
\hat \theta_n \rightarrow \mathcal N(\theta^o,B(\theta^o)),
\end{equation*}
where $\theta^o$ is the true parameter.

Here, confusion arises for me that the support of the Gaussian distribution is the whole space of $\mathbb R^d$, while the constrained maximum likelihood estimate $\hat \theta_n$ should satisfy the constraint $f(\hat \theta_n)=0$ whose feasible set is generally not $\mathbb R^d$. So, how can we understand the asymptotic normality of the constrained maximum likelihood estimate?

Thanks!

[1] Moore, Terrence J., Brian M. Sadler, and Richard J. Kozick. "Maximum-likelihood estimation, the Cramér–Rao bound, and the method of scoring with parameter constraints." IEEE Transactions on Signal Processing 56.3 (2008): 895-908.